# Preventing a control from receiving focus when using the Tab key

Tags: c#, controls

How does one set a `TextBox` control so that it has no `TabIndex` at all.

I want to make it so that the user **can't** tab into it.

**[explanation]**
The reason I asked this question is because I recently switched from vb to c#, and am trying out the QuickSharp SDK.  If you use that system, then you have to build your forms without Visual Studio's visual designer - hence, there is no GUI to help you in setting all the properties of the form.  It's a good learning experience, however.

So, it may seem a trivial question, but under the circumstances, I think it is a legitimate question.

Comment: Why the close vote? I even googled for the answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx) : For a control to be included in the tab order, its TabStop property must be set to true.

So setting the TabStop property to `false` should remove it from the TabOrder

Answer (score 1):

If this is Winforms, you set the TabStop property to false.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Winforms then you can use [Control.TabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop.aspx) Property

```
button1.TabStop = false;
```

For asp, you can also use `tabindex="-1".`

The [W3C HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) supports negative tabindex values:
The summary of above documentation is

> If the value is a negative integer,The user agent must set the element's tabindex focus flag, but should not allow the element to be reached using sequential focus navigation.